# Cálculo com virgula em PHP

Tags: php

Preciso multiplicar o valor recebido do formulário post Ex: $altura * $largura * 45;
Até aí tudo bem, mas se o usuário digitar um valor com virgula, a soma não acontece.

Eu preciso que a soma aconteça de ambas formas, e não que me mostre o resultado com number_format() apenas.

```
<?php 
// Exemplo com POST
$altura = $_POST['alt'];
$largura = $_POST['larg'];
$valor = "45";
$soma = $altura * $largura * $valor; // Soma: Altura * Largura * Valor.
echo $soma
?>  

<?php 
// Exemplo cru com vírgula
$altura = "1,20";
$largura = "0,90"; 
$valor = "45,00";
$soma = $altura * $largura * 45; // Soma: Altura * Largura * Valor.
echo $soma
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O separador decimal é `.`(ponto) e não `,`(virgula), para resolver isso você pode usar [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) para trocar as ocorrências de virgulas por pontos.

<sub>Nenhuma soma é realizada :P parece que o sinal de mais foi trocado pelo de multiplicação.</sub>

```
$altura = "1,20";
$largura = "0,90";
$valor = "45,00";


$altura = str_replace(',', '.', $altura);
$largura = str_replace(',', '.', $largura);
$valor = str_replace(',', '.', $valor);

$multiplicao= $altura * $largura * 45; // multiplica: Altura * Largura * Valor.
echo $multiplicao;
```