# Erro ao multiplicar decimal por inteiro em php

Tags: php, matemática

Segue o exemplo de meu código:

```
$v_quantidade = 10;
$v_preco = '3,68' ;
$v_total   = $v_preco * $v_quantidade;
echo "$v_total";
```

A minha variável **$v_quantidade** ela trás numero inteiros, exemplo: 3..5..10..20..etc ...

A minha variável **$v_preco** trás o preço, exemplo: 3,68.

Quando faço o calculo mostrado acima esta retornando errado,esse calculo ai do exemplo esta retornando **10.**

O que estou fazendo errado ?

E se possível também outra dúvida junto, alguns preços podem vir assim: **3,689** como apresento no php somente o **3,68**

Comment: A virgula não é separador de decimal.

Comment: [Cálculo com virgula em PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44653/91)

Comment: @rray Bom dia, eu pego essa informação no banco e vem dessa forma,como poderia tratar ? Alguma dica?

Comment: @rray Perfeito,deu certo. Só mais uma duvida,ele retornou assim: 36.8 como faço para retornar assim 36,80 ?

Comment: Com [numberFormatter](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.numberformatter.php)

Comment: [Formatação de números](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11301/91)

Comment: Obrigado Diego F e rray,tudo perfeito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue solução elaborada com as dicas de @Diego F e @rray

```
  $v_quantidade = 10;
  $v_preco  = '3,68' ;
  $v_preco  = str_replace(',', '.', $v_preco);
  $v_numero = $v_quantidade * $v_preco; 
  $v_total  = number_format($v_numero, 2, ',', '.');
  echo "<p><b>VALOR TOTAL: R$ $v_total                  </br></p>";
```