# Como somar valores em php?

Tags: php

Bom dia pessoal,

Quero somar valores de um formulário, mas não estou conseguindo.
Preciso fazer o seguinte cálculo:

```
<?php
vlMateriaPrima = 3,05;
$isumosMateriais = 0,25;
$embalagem = 0,50;

$custoDireto = vlMateriaPrima + $isumosMateriais + $embalagem;
?>
```

Esses valores devem ser preenchidos com vírgula, no formulário.
O resultado é para ser 3,80 e sai apenas 3

Comment: Com virgula ele nao soma, precisa ser com `.`

Comment: Troque as `,` por `.` e depois faça a soma.

Comment: [Cálculo com virgula em PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44653/91) e 
[Centavos corretos nos boletos bancários da BoletoPHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104193/91)

Comment: Pois é, tentei usar "number_format($valor,2,'.',',')" para converter a variável, mas da o seguinte erro "Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered"

Comment: Tenho a resposta, mas não consegui postar.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3xB3aadw aqui, tente dessa forma.

Comment: Valeu @rray, fechou!
$vlMateriaPrima = str_replace(',', '.', $vlMateriaPrima);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os decimais em PHP são separados por `.` (ponto) e não há separadores de milhares.

Faça assim:

```
<?php
vlMateriaPrima = 3.05;
$isumosMateriais = 0.25;
$embalagem = 0.50;

$custoDireto = vlMateriaPrima + $isumosMateriais + $embalagem;
?>
```

Se você recebe os dados com formato separando decimais com vírgula, pode fazer assim:

```
<?php
function moedaPhp($str_num){
    $resultado = str_replace('.', '', $str_num);
    $resultado = str_replace(',', '.', $resultado);
    return $resultado;
}

echo moedaPhp('12.654,56'); // retorna: 12654.56
```

Comment: Cara, os valores vem de inputs em formato 0,00. Mas não sei como convertê-los para 0.00.

Comment: @GustavoSevero, atualizei a resposta.