# Formatar número php

Tags: php

Tenho a variável `$valor` que me retorna

```
10,00
```

Necessitava formatar esse número para

```
10.00
```

No lugar da vírgula **`,`** colocar um ponto **`.`**

Tentei usar a função `number_format($valor, 2, '.', '')` porém está dando erro e não consigo.

Alguém tem uma solução?

Erro encontrado:

> ```
> "A non well formed numeric value encountered in line 15 "
> ```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Cálculo com virgula em PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44653/c%c3%a1lculo-com-virgula-em-php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Faz assim:

```
$novoValor = str_replace(',', '.', $valor);
```

Comment: Perfeito! Funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Mesmo colocando a resposta acima como certa, a tua função `number_format` está com uso equivocado:

```
number_format($valor, 2, ',', '.');
```

Ela não realiza o `CAST` de um número, apenas o formata. Dessa forma que coloquei, coloca um número pronto para leitura nos moldes brasileiros.